# Regression train dataset in loop with different algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have read the data from pandas and want to pass in different algorithms to find the score.

**Option 1**

```
data=pd.read_excel("El Nino.xlsx")
# Scaled the data further and then split into independent and dependent variables.
R1= LinearRegression.fit(X_train,y_train)
R2= Ridge.fit(X_train,y_train)
R3=Perceptron.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

**Option 2**
I would like to pass it in loop ...something like this

```
estimators = ["LinearRegression", "Ridge", "PassiveAggressiveClassifier","Perceptron"]

for i in estimators:
    reg= i.fit(X_train,y_train)
    Score= reg.score(X_train,y_train)
    print(Score)
```

It doesn't work as the items in the list are strings.  Can you please suggest the way I can pass it in loop to train and calculate the score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, I misunderstood the problem. Souldn't you just pass in your Estimator loop your fitted models, like `estimators = [R1, R2, R3]` ?

Or if you want to make your loop like that you have to call the object `LinearRegression` for example, not make a string :

```
lr = LinearRegression()
rg = Ridge()
pac = PassiveAggressiveClassifier()
ptn = Perceptron()
estimators = [lr,rg,pac,ptn]
```

as you did in the function before

Comment: This approach will not work. 

estimators = [LinearRegression(), Ridge(), PassiveAggressiveClassifier(),Perceptron()]




NameError: name 'LinearRegression' is not defined

Comment: Then set variables before, like lr = LogisticRegression(), ridge = Ridge(), ... and estimators = [lr, ridge, ... ]